# cannot read properties of null(reading body)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

Here is the Error
node:events:491
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'body')
at E:\Users2\Desktop\Codeial\codeial\controllers\comment_controller.js:9:29
at E:\Users2\Desktop\Codeial\codeial\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:5228:18
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
at E:\Users2\Desktop\Codeial\codeial\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:5230:15
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)

Here is the code in which the error occurs

```
const Comment = require('../models/comments');
const Post = require('../models/posts');

module.exports.create = (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body);
    Post.findById(req.body.post, (req, res) => {  
        console.log(req.body.matter);
        if(post){
            Comment.create({
                matter: req.body.matter,
                post: req.body.post,
                user: req.user._id
            }, function(err, comment){
                if(err){
                    console.log("Error : tranfering the comment into the respective array")
                }
                post.comments.push(comment);
                post.save();
                res.redirect('/');
                
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Basically it is not reading the :-

```
matter: req.body.matter
```

Here is the ejs file where the output goes

```
<div id="post-comments">
                    <% if(locals.user){%>
                    <form action="/comments/create" method="POST">
                        <input type="text" name="matter" placeholder="Add your comment here...">
                        <input type="hidden" name="post" value="<%= post._id %>">
                        <input type="submit" value="post">
                    </form>
                    <%}%>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats the result of console.log(req.body)?

Answer (score 0):

You use the key word `req` in two different places, so the second req are overwrite the first one.

try this code :

```
module.exports.create = (request, response) => {
    console.log(request.body);
    Post.findById(request.body.post, (err, post) => {  
        console.log(request.body.matter);
        if(post){
            Comment.create({
                matter: request.body.matter,
                post: request.body.post,
                user: request.user._id
            }, function(error, comment){
                if(error){
                    console.log("Error : tranfering the comment into the respective array")
                }
                post.comments.push(comment);
                post.save();
                response.redirect('/');
                
            })
        }
    })
}
```